# Probability Question: Independence

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

My stats prof posted an answer but it doesn't make sense. Please help!

$A$, $B$, $C$ are mutually independent. Prove $A$ and $B^c ∪ C$ are independent?
($B^c$ = $B$ complement)

My stats professor posted this answer, but I don't get where he got the first line in the proof. Shouldn't it be $P(A \cap (B^c \cup C))$? 
Would really appreciate it if anyone could explain. Thank you so much!

Proof: 
$$P(A∪(B^c ∩C))=P((A∩B^c)∪(A∩C)) $$

$$= P(AB^c) + P(AC) − P(AB^cC) $$

$$= P(A)P(B^c) + P(A)P(C) − P(A)P(B^c)P(C),\text{ because they are mutually independent.}$$

$$= P(A)(P(B^c) + P(C) − P(B^cC)) $$

$$=P(A)P(B^c ∪C) $$

Thus, $A$ and $B^c ∪ C$ are independent.

Comment: Yes you are right: in the very first expression tou should indeed have: $$P(A\cap (B^c\cup C)),$$ from that the proof follows as it is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the first line should say $P(A \cap (B^C \cup C))$. However, let's assume we have that instead. Then, we can distribute the $A\cap$ over $B^C \cup C$ to get $P((A \cap B^C) \cup (A \cap C))$. This is exactly where the professor went, so from then on, the proof is correct. It is just a typo in the first line; everything else in the proof is correct.